# UIMA RUTA Combination of Annotations

Tags: annotations, uima, ruta

I am new to UIMA RUTA and after reading the UIMA RUTA Guide, I have the following question. I want to write a set of rules that will search for two annotations (FIRST, SECOND) inside my document with specific values (FIRST: "hello" and SECOND: "world","pres") and if they find them it will create a new annotation (THIRD) with value:"end".
However, the script is not working and I am wondering why.

```
WORDTABLE Firsts= 'FIRST.csv';
WORDTABLE Seconds= 'SECOND.csv';
WORDTABLE Thirds= 'THIRD.csv';
DECLARE Annotation FIRST(STRING value);
DECLARE Annotation SECOND(STRING value, STRING pos);
DECLARE Annotation THIRD(STRING value);
Document{->MARKTABLE(FIRST, 1, Firsts, "value"=2)};
Document{->MARKTABLE(SECOND, 1, Seconds, "value"=2, "pos"=3)};
Document{AND(CONTAINS(FIRST{FEATURE("value","hello")}),CONTAINS(SECOND{FEATURE("value","world","pos","pres")})){->CREATE(THIRD{FEATURE("value","end")})}};
```

Could you please help me out? Thanx.

Comment: For this No need to use wordtable. Wordlist is enough.

Comment: I assume that he needs  MARKTABLE because of the feature `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last rule is not valid.

You could write something like:

```
(f:FIRST{f.value=="hello"} # s:SECOND{s.value=="world",s.pos=="pres"}){-> CREATE(THIRD, "value" = "end")};
```

or

```
Document{-> CREATE(THIRD, "value" = "end")}<-{f:FIRST{f.value=="hello"} # s:SECOND{s.value=="world",s.pos=="pres"};};
```

or something with a conjunct rule.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: And how do I throw the CONTAINS and conjunction (AND) conditions in there?

Comment: In the seoncd rule, the inlined rule acts as a contains combined with an AND. The only difference is that there is also a sequential constraint.

Comment: And if I would like to get rid of this sequential constraint (maybe for a future project or something), how could I do that? I mean that it seems that the approach above presupposes that the FIRST annotation occurs before the SECOND, right? What would be a more general approach, independently of the order of the annotations?

Comment: There are several options: use an additional second rule or replace the inlined rules with conjunct rules.

Comment: Multiple markers:
-error: Feature "f.value==RutaStringExpression : ["Open"]" is not defined for type "f".
-Type "f.value " not defined in this script/block!

Comment: The rule should work in UIMA Ruta 2.6.0. Could be that the Workbench complains but that can be ignored (is already fixed for next release)